# Python Tkinter Entry Field Value Comparison Problems

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to develop a program that a user enters in some text then press submit and it would take the text in the entry field and compare it to another value.

```
root=Tk()
win1=Frame(root)
txt=Entry(root)
def get_name():
if(txt.get()=="hello"):
    print ("hello")
v=Button(root,text="Submit",command=get_name())


v.pack()
txt.pack()
win1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code is intended to print to the console "hello" if "hello" is written in the entry field before the user presses submit. However, the code does not print "hello" to the console, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a reference to a function (without the parentheses) to the `command` option. If you don't remove the parentheses, what you are doing is calling the function:

```
v=Button(root,text="Submit",command=get_name)
```